# Jira post commit hook

Tags: jira

Is there a Jira post commit hook where if someone commits something and changes a ticket to a specific status, one can run anohter outside process? Let's say creating a test environment for that specific patch on a remote machine?

Comment: It's possible by creating a plugin either with event listener or workflow post function...

Comment: Any chance you can give me some document references about event listeners in a plugin? Documentation to workflow post function I already read about

Comment: You can try this: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/other/tutorial-writing-jira-event-listeners-with-the-atlassian-event-library

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated